# ¿Cómo traducir caracteres escritos en "input()" pero escritos en un cuadro de dialogo en una interfaz?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-3.7

Necesito ayuda :(
La cosa es que quería crear una especie de traductor pero para codificar un texto y que así no se sepa qué escribí

ya tengo el código y ya sé como se puede modificar dentro de la consola, pero quiero modificarlo cuando escriben las frases dentro de una interfaz.

Osea, cuando creo un cuadro de dialogo para que la gente escriba, funciona, pero luego no sé como poner el evento para traducir lo escrito y que aparesca en otro label

Según entiendo se usa un ".get" pero no sé mucho cómo usarlo

Esto es lo que tengo yo:

```
frase=input("Escribe la palabra a traducir: ")


traduccio=frase.replace('j','θЧ')
traduccion=traduccio.replace('w','θφ')
traduccionn=traduccion.replace('ñ','ЧѦ')

espacios=traduccionn.replace(' ','˜')

entrada="abcdefghilmnopqrstuvxyz."

salida="æ&ødêτЧθëυγѦœρƸηжΩõφ§×λ¯"
cambio=espacios.maketrans(entrada,salida)

print("^"+espacios.translate(cambio))
```

```
ventana=tk.Tk()
ventana.title("traductor")
ventana.geometry('200x300')
ventana.configure(background='white')

frase=tk.Entry(ventana)
frase.pack(fill=tk.X,padx=5,pady=5,ipadx=5,ipady=5)


root = tk.Button(ventana,text="Traducir:",bg="black",fg="white")
root.pack(padx=20,pady=10)
```

Pedí ayuda y me dieron un código que funciona perfecto con otra forma de traduccion

```
import tkinter as tk
def translate():
    #==== Forget the position of the widgets in the window
    for widget in ventana.winfo_children():
        widget.pack_forget()
    #=== Again place the entry box and the button
    frase.pack(fill=tk.X,padx=5,pady=5,ipadx=5,ipady=5)
    root.pack(padx=20,pady=10)
    #==== Provide the text entered in the entry field
    entrada="abcdefghilmnopqrstuvxyz"
    salida="mnopqrstuvxyzabcdefghil"
    letras=org_phrase.get().maketrans(entrada,salida)
    #===print the translation (optional)
    print(org_phrase.get().translate(letras))
    #=== set it as label to display it
    tk.Label(ventana,bg="white",text=org_phrase.get().translate(letras)).pack()
ventana=tk.Tk()
ventana.title("traductor")
ventana.geometry('200x300')
ventana.configure(background='white')
#=== Using stringvar to get the value
org_phrase=tk.StringVar()
#trans_phrase=tk.StringVar()
frase=tk.Entry(ventana,textvariable=org_phrase)
frase.pack(fill=tk.X,padx=5,pady=5,ipadx=5,ipady=5)

root =tk.Button(ventana,text="Traducir:",bg="black",fg="white",command=translate)
root.pack(padx=20,pady=10)
root.mainloop()
```

Pero quería aprender como hacerlo yo mismo y arriba la verdad no entendía muy bien
me podrían explicar esto porfavor?
Quiero aprender a usar el get y el stringvar

Además de poder entender todo esto de abajo

```
for widget in ventana.winfo_children():
        widget.pack_forget()
    #=== Again place the entry box and the button
    frase.pack(fill=tk.X,padx=5,pady=5,ipadx=5,ipady=5)
    root.pack(padx=20,pady=10)
    #==== Provide the text entered in the entry field
    entrada="abcdefghilmnopqrstuvxyz"
    salida="mnopqrstuvxyzabcdefghil"
    letras=org_phrase.get().maketrans(entrada,salida)
    #===print the translation (optional)
    print(org_phrase.get().translate(letras))
```

Se más o menos qué significa, pero por ejemplo no entiendo lo de ".winfo_children"
Ni tampoco sé porque puso esto denuevo siendo que estaba escrito abajo

"frase.pack(fill=tk.X,padx=5,pady=5,ipadx=5,ipady=5)
root.pack(padx=20,pady=10)"

PD: tambien, si saben cómo puedo hacer para poder traducir una frase larga y que aparezca completa, porque cuando pongo una muy larga, la conversión me aparece incompleta porque es demasiado larga xd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes valerte del uso de una StringVar usando el método *trace*, lo que provoca que se llame una función cada vez que cambia el valor de la variable, te dejo un ejemplo de cómo declararlo:

```
import tkinter as tk

def callback(miVar):
    print('El nuevo valor de miVar es: ', miVar.get())

raiz = tk.Tk()
miVar = tk.StringVar()
miVar.trace("w", lambda name, index, mode, sv=miVar: callback(miVar))
e = tk.Entry(raiz, textvariable=miVar)
e.pack()
raiz.mainloop()
```